# I'm getting an error while importing the "ngx-bootstrap/datepicker" module in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap-calendar

I am trying to import the ngx Bootstrap datepicker in my Angular Application
for that I followed the following stapes

1. to npm install ngx-bootstrap

   npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
2. Installed bootstrap 3

   npm install bootstrap@3 --save
3. In angular-cli.json file and specify the path to the Bootstrap stylesheet (bootstrap.min.css) in the styles property

   "styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
     "styles.css"
   ]
4. For Using ngx-bootstrap datepicker in Angular :
5. In app.module.ts file, imported BsDatepickerModule

   import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
6. In html used

   > bsDatepicker

   class="form-control" />

   7. Include a reference to the bs-datepicker.css file in .angular-cli.json file.

      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
        "styles.css"
      ]

> but I am getting error while running the Angular Application
>
> ```
> ERROR in multi ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
> ```
>
> ../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css
>   ./src/styles.css
>
> ```
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
> ```
>
> in '/Users/user/Projects/CRUD' ERROR in multi
>   ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   ../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css
>   ./src/styles.css
>
> ```
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/user/Projects/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css'
> ```
>
> in '/Users/user/Projects/CRUD'

I am putting all the information of code below -:

**I am putting angular.json file code below**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "CRUD": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/CRUD",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CRUD:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "CRUD:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CRUD:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "CRUD-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "CRUD:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "CRUD:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "CRUD"
}
```

**Package.json code - :**

```
{
  "name": "crud",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts code**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule , Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ListEmployeesComponent } from './employees/list-employees.component';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './employees/create-employee.component';


import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'list', component: ListEmployeesComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: CreateEmployeeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/list', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListEmployeesComponent,
    CreateEmployeeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you are importing css files from wrong location. edit `angular.json` file like(remove **../**: ```"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],```

Comment: thanks @suhailvs ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I correct the importing css files location my error is fixed .
 I edited `angular.json` file like as below

```
(remove ../: "styles": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css", "src/styles.css" ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
@import "~ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";
```

And I just changed it to:

```
@import "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this command:

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap
```

Comment: Please improve formatting and add some explanation why this command is helpful :)